# How to access Parent Fragment data from Child Fragment using MVVM pattern with Livedata in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

I have a list Fragment where recyclerview is used to displayed the list when the use presses on the list item user goes to new fragment(parent fragment) where i have setup a tablayout with 2 fragments(detail fragment and second fragment) using viewpager2. Here the data from list item is passed to parent fragment using Bundle. i need to get access this data which is available in parent fragment and use it to display data in child fragment(detail fragment)

i am using hilt as dependency injection.

list fragment code to send data

```
 private val mylistsViewModel by viewModels<MyListsViewModel>()
    private var mylists: MyListsResponse? = null
.......
`    private fun onItemClicked(mylistsResponse: MyListsResponse) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("mylist",Gson().toJson(mylistsResponse))
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mylistsFragment_to_parentFragment,bundle)
    }`
```

accessing it in parent fragment

```
 private val mylistsViewModel by viewModels<MyListsViewModel>()
    private var mylists: MyListsResponse? = null
.......

        val jsonMyLists = arguments?.getString("mylist")
        if (jsonMyLists != null) {
            mylists = Gson().fromJson<MyListsResponse>(jsonMyLists, MyListsResponse::class.java)
            mylists?.let {


            }
        }
```

**UI Flow**

[access data from parent to child fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwm7q.png)

Can any one kindly suggest on how to resolve this issue.

i refered this [googleDocs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#share_data_between_a_parent_and_child_fragment)

and tried to access the data in details fragment by refering to this code

```
class ListFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel
    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.filteredList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
            // Update the list UI
        }
    }
}

class ChildFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel using the parent fragment's scope
    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by viewModels({requireParentFragment()})
    ...
}
```

But when i go to detail fragment the app is crashing and giving error as

"Fragment DetailsFragment is not a child Fragment, it is directly attached to dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are using the Navigation component to handle navigation in your application `requireParentFragment` will return an instance of the `NavHostFragment` which is not `ListFragment` as you expected.
Fortunately, there is a way to instantiate a view model using the navigation component `backStackEntry` and Hilt as follows:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ListFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel
    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by lazy {
        val destination = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry!!.destination

        val backStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(destination.id)

        val storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore = {
            backStackEntry.viewModelStore
        }

        createViewModelLazy(
            ListViewModel::class, storeProducer,
            factoryProducer = {
                HiltViewModelFactory(requireActivity(), backStackEntry)
            }
        ).value
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.filteredList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
            // Update the list UI
        }
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChildFragment: Fragment() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the fragment-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel using the parent fragment's scope
    private val viewModel: ListViewModel by lazy {
        val destination = findNavController().previousBackStackEntry!!.destination

        val backStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(destination.id)

        val storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore = {
            backStackEntry.viewModelStore
        }

        createViewModelLazy(
            ListViewModel::class, storeProducer,
            factoryProducer = {
                HiltViewModelFactory(requireActivity(), backStackEntry)
            }
        ).value
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, don't forget to annotate the `ListViewModel` with `@HiltViewModel`.

This way of implementation can work with any fragment and the previous one as you may notice in the `ChildFragment` we are using `previousBackStackEntry` instead of `currentBackStackEntry` in the `ListFragment`